# Why is Date query with aggregate is not working in parse-server?

Tags: parse-server

I want to query user where updatedAt is less than or equal today using aggregate because I'm doing other stuff like sorting by pointers.

I'm using cloud code to define the query from the server.
I first tried using mongoDB Compass to check my query using ISODate and it works, but using it in NodeJS seems not working correctly.

I also noticed about this problem that was already fix, they say. I also saw their tests.

Here's a [link](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/4678) to that PR.

I'm passing date like this:

```js
const pipeline = [
  {
    project: {
      _id: true,
      process: {
        $substr: ['$_p_testdata', 12, -1]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    lookup: {
      from: 'Test',
      localField: 'process',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'process'
    }
  },
  {
    unwind: {
      path: '$process'
    }
  },
  {
    match: {
      'process._updated_at': {
         $lte: new Date()
      }
    }
  }
];

const query = new Parse.Query('data');
return query.aggregate(pipeline);
```

I expect value to be an array with length of 4 but only give me empty array.

I was able to fetch data without match date.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
const pipeline = [
  {
    match: {
      'editedBy.updatedAt': {
         $lte: new Date()
      }
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: nope, where accessing parse object directly using mongodb so I use "_updated_at"

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? Parse Server should automatically convert updatedAt to _updated_at (https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/spec/ParseQuery.Aggregate.spec.js#L823). I am only not sure about the "." notation. Maybe it is making Parse server to fail. Let me know so I can potentially help to fix.

Comment: It seems like parse was not compatible when you used $project and make a match out of it.